# Failed to resolve Android.App after upgrade Xamarin 5

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I've updated my pcl project to Xamarin.Forms 5, but after this the build fails to resolve Android.App namespace.
I need to get the context from Android native project, like so:

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
```

Before the update, this code worked fine.
I think that is any incompatibility due to new AndroidX library, but I don't undestanding how can I resolve it.

Comment: There are some breaking changes when moving to Xamarin 5. Have you been through the release notes and checked that you've covered them all?

Comment: @GazWinter: Yes, I've readed release notes, and I fixed many others issues, but this still not working

Comment: So i started a new forms project, upgraded to xamarin 5, targeted android 10 and called that in my first line of the activity and it works.

Comment: Try to delete the folder bin and obj in your project then clean and rebuild it . If it still doesn't work on your side , check the plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin .

Comment: I've uninstalled all packages from native project and re-installed Xamarin.Forms 4.8 package only, but still not works.

Comment: Ok, I've solved installing CurrentActivityPlugin, but I still not undertand why the update raised this error.